# React:How to use geolocation and nearby search in react to find nearby restaurants

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me how to use geolocation and nearbysearch() in react to find nearby restaurants using google API. I have already implemented it in java script but couldn't be exact how to do in React! I have partially implemented in react. Below is my code in app.js(container):

The below code gets executed displaying a map with current location.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Map, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';

import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {}
    }
    // binding this to event-handler functions
    this.onMarkerClick = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.onMapClick = this.onMapClick.bind(this);
  }

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    //alert(props.zoom);
     this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  }

  onMapClick = (props) => {
    //alert(props.xs);
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  }

  createMarkers = (props) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    this.onMarkerClick(results[i])
    }}

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '100vw',
      height: '150vh',
      'marginLeft': 'auto',
      'marginRight': 'auto'
    }

    return (
      <Map
        item
        xs = { 12 }
        style = { style }
        google = { this.props.google }
        onClick = { this.onMapClick }
        zoom = { 14 }
        initialCenter = {{ lat: 1.346648, lng: 103.84991200 }}
      >
        <Marker
          onClick = { this.onMarkerClick }
          title = { 'Home' }
          position = {{ lat: 1.346648, lng: 103.84991200 }}
          name = { 'Home' }
        />
        <InfoWindow
          marker = { this.state.activeMarker }
          visible = { this.state.showingInfoWindow }
        >
          <Paper>
            <Typography
              variant = 'headline'
              component = 'h4'
            >
              Home
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              component = 'p'
            >
               Bishan
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
        </InfoWindow>
```

From the below lines I get an error that 'type arguments' can only be used in .ts file, when i try to create a button.kindly guide me what does the error mean and how can it be resolved?

```
        <Marker
         <button onClick = {this.createMarkers}>Try Me</button>

         />
         <InfoWindow
          marker = { this.state.activeMarker }
          visible = { this.state.showingInfoWindow }
        >
          <Paper>
            <Typography
              variant = 'headline'
              component = 'h4'
            >
              {props.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              component = 'p'
            >
            {props.vicinity}            
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
        </InfoWindow>

      </Map>




    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    api: (process.env.API key)
})(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert typed address into lat/lng

```
 function codeAddress() {
    var address = addressForSearch;
    geocoder.geocode(
      {
        address: address,
      },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
          });
        } else {
          alert(
            'Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
              status,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

(Don't forget to init the function eg:)

```
function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  codeAddress();
  ..
```

To performe a search you can do it like that:

```
 function performSearch() {
    var request = {
      bounds: map.getBounds(),
      type: 'restaurant',
      keyword: '-burgerking',
    };
    service.radarSearch(request, callback);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you help me with React code? @ckappo

Comment: sry mate I have no react example. But look at: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#searchbox. This example will help you